# How to read back a nulllable DateTime using SQL Data Reader?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, properties, nullable, sqldatareader

I've declared a nullable `DateTime? NextUpdate`property in my model and database.

I can update the DateTime value fine on my DB as it allows null for this field.

But when I try to *get* the value of `NextUpdate` field from the database using SQL Data Reader it bombs out because the value of NextUpdate is null.

I did try to init the NextUpdate value if it is null using the following assignment but the error is still thrown telling me that field is null:

```
NextUpdate = dataReader.GetDateTime(dataReader.GetOrdinal("NextUpdate")) != null ? dataReader.GetDateTime(dataReader.GetOrdinal("NextUpdate")) : DateTime.MinValue,
```

Error:

```
Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values -  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_DateTime()
```

Question:

Is there a short method of reading back and initializing a nullable `**DateTime?**` value?

Code:

```
using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
{
   if (dataReader.Read())
   {
      esc = new Escalation
      {
          NextUpdate = dataReader.GetDateTime(dataReader.GetOrdinal("NextUpdate")),
          RootCause = dataReader["RootCause"] != null ? dataReader["EM"].ToString() : ""
      };
   }
}
```

Property in Model:

```
    public DateTime? NextUpdate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `IDataReader ` always have a column named `NextUpdate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the value against `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`:

```
NextUpdate = dataReader["NextUpdate"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)dataReader["NextUpdate"]
```

(assuming that the `NextUpdate` member is a `DateTime?`)

Answer (score 0):

Try following expression:

```
RootCause = (dataReader["RootCause"] is DBNull) ? (DateTime?)null :  (DateTime?)dataReader["RootCause"] ;
```

Comment: NextUpdate is the DateTime? field not RootCause.

Comment: @Brian J  exactly.